# Why do the even integers form a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that this seems like a really easy question, but I really don't understand it.

My, clearly flawed, thought process is that the even integers do not contain the multiplicative identity (1)

Comment: Then they form a ring without unity.

Comment: This depends on your definition of what a "ring" is. Many authors do not assume rings to be unital, i.e. they don't necessarily need to have a multiplicative identity.

Comment: The definition of Ring does not require the ring to contain multiplicative identity. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: The answer depends on your definition of "ring". Sometimes (but usually not unless it's made explicit)  rings have to have a multiplicative identity. Clearly not, in this case. (There's always a $0$.)

Comment: I love how there were 4 comments within 1 minute that completely resolve the question. One of you should post an answer so that OP can choose a best answer and end the thread.

Comment: @Hayden A ring R is a set together with two binary operations
(usually, but not always, written +, ·) called “addition” and “multiplication”, such that
+ makes R into an abelian group, and such that the following conditions hold:
i) [Identity] There exists an element 1 ∈ R such that 1 · x = x · 1 = x, for all x ∈ R.
ii) [Associativity] For any x, y, z ∈ R we have x(yz) = (xy)z.
iii) [Distributivity] For any x, y, z ∈ R we have x(y+z) = xy+xz and (y+z)x = yx+zx       This is the definition I have. I just always presumed it needed addition and multiplication identities

Comment: @DanielMcElroy And the same text that gives that definition says that $2\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring (with unity)? If so, it is either a typo or they have different definitions of operations on $2\mathbb{Z}$ (for example, they could define $(2n) \ast (2m) = nm$)

Comment: @Hayden Nope. It is a question asking whether the even integers form a group, which I thought was no

Comment: @DanielMcElroy That is an entirely different question then that doesn't seem to involve rings at all. Under integer addition, $2\mathbb{Z}$ is an Abelian group.

Comment: @Hayden Sorry. I meant to put ring. I'm just not thinking straight at the moment because I'm stressing out. http://puu.sh/vmd0H/26ce7d2ecd.png this is the question exactly how it is written

Comment: @DanielMcElroy That isn't saying that $2\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual operations is a ring, it's asking whether it is a ring. Technically speaking, the observation that $1\notin 2\mathbb{Z}$ is not enough to show that it doesn't contain an identity element, but cancellation shows that if we had such an identity $e$, then $2ne=2n$ for all $e$, so taking $n=1$ and using cancellation gives that $e=1$, and indeed $1\notin 2\mathbb{Z}$.  Hence, it is not a ring.

Comment: @hayden But the solution to the question is "Yes"

Comment: @DanielMcElroy Then it is wrong, according to your definition of ring.

Comment: @DanielMcElroy Which book are you using?

Comment: @Hayden Okay, that has calmed me down a bit

Comment: @SantanaAfton No book. Just questions and notes provided by lecturer